# team work in latex

Tags: texmaker, collaboration

I'm  in a team with 5 other people and we are all kind of novice in latex.We want to write a book using latex and I would like to ask whether there exist a way to divide the work by working in the same project from different PCs.

Comment: You could use git to do so.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what git is

Comment: Git is a version control system and especially for text based files like TeX files it is great. You could use gitlab.com as a platform (allows private projects). But really an introduction to Git is off-topic here.

Comment: you can work on separate files using any system you like, or you could use one of the online systems like sharelatex/overleaf that allow online shared editing of the same content

Comment: @ David Carlisle  so this can be done using sharelatex? Could you be more specific on that?

Comment: I don't actually have a sharelatex account but since the headline on their home page says `The easy to use, online, collaborative LaTeX editor`  I assume it supports these things

Comment: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Sharing_your_work_with_others

Comment: Collaborative work on ShareLaTex seems to require a payed account, see https://www.sharelatex.com/user/subscription/plans.

Comment: @epR8GaYuh Is there a way to do collaborative work online without paying?

Comment: Overleaf seems to support collaborative work (see https://www.overleaf.com/plans) for free after signing up, but for real private projects only accessible by the collaborators you need to pay, too.

Comment: despite suggesting the online collaboration possibilities If writing a book I would use git (and collaborate via github unless it needs to be private) as using source control is a good thing to do in any case.

Comment: Dropbox also works fine. Just make sure that you do not compile in the dropbox folder. Rather, compile in a local folder and use softlinks, e.g. `ln -s ~/Dropbox/Book/book.tex`.